# Fetching multiple rows not working when using 'AS'

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Fetching multiple rows not working when using 'AS'

For example,

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, (cpm/SUM(cpm)) AS Importance FROM ads")
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $Importance);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo $id;
}
```

will only print out row with id #1 when there are 2 rows. But, if I take out '(cpm/SUM(cpm)) AS Importance', the while loop fetches both rows.

Thank you

Comment: It's not the `AS`, it's the `SUM` aggregate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SUM function makes it calculate a single result over all rows. Using it in a division doesn't change that, not even the AS statement. Instead it will use one of the rows (the first or last one) for the division. The same goes for other aggregating functions, for instance COUNT.

To achieve your goal you can use an additional select for the SUM and use the result of that to calculate the division for all entries, for instance like this: `SELECT id, (cpm/(SELECT SUM(cpm) FROM ads)) AS Importance FROM ads;`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use GROUP BY when using aggregate functions for multiple rows 
for e.g

```
SELECT id, (cpm/SUM(cpm)) AS Importance FROM ads GROUP BY field_name
```